# How to undo xcode discard all changes if not committed

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a iOS project that I have some changes haven't commit. I clicked discard all changes mistakenly. I actually want to only discard a specific file's changes. But I clicked wrong button. And now everything are gone. How to undo the changes?

git status shows nothing.

Comment: In Terminal, type git reflog...what do you see?

Comment: @BHendricks I see the commit histories. But I haven't committed yet. Can I give it back?

Comment: were your changes staged at all?

Comment: Do hourly backups! Time machine is a life saver! Obviously you'll lose anything within the last hour, but if you happened to step away for a while and accidentally did it when you came back, you're ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck. See this answer:
    [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Since you did not commit, or stage any of your files, then having reverted them means they are lost.

Sorry.

Comment: They are not lost if you are on a mac! Check the next answer

Answer (score 152):

You might *not* be out of luck. Although Git can't help you, Finder may be able to come to the rescue!

If you have not turned off the Versions feature (which by default is turned on and you need a Terminal command to disable), then do the following:

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Open the file you wish to bring back your lost changes to using TextEdit.
3. Go to File > Revert To > Browse All Versions...
4. Scroll through the available versions. Hopefully you will have many available to choose from.
5. Select a version and hit Restore.
6. Follow 2-5 for all necessary files.
7. Launch Xcode. You should now see the `M` next to these files in Project Navigator indicating they include uncommited changes (the changes you previously discarded).

Completely new files you may have created and were discarded can be found in the *Trash*.

Also a small piece of advice. If you are in need to discard changes, prefer using *Source Control > Discard Changes* by right clicking on files in the Project Navigator, instead of *Discard All Changes* which might give you all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Hey there, I am new to git and posted my question [here][1]  

Basically i have done the same thing, but I was in the process of trying to setup a git workflow on a project I have spent 6 months working on. I found the project in the trash with the files and code, but after I restored to the desktop the project does not display anything. So how can i restore correctly from the trash ? 

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297971/restoring-project-after-discarded-all-changes-to-xcode-project?noredirect=1#comment65931886_39297971

Comment: I created a CLI for your solution! https://github.com/cprovatas/git-recover It uses the `NSFileVersion` API that TextEdit uses to more easily recover your changes

Comment: what if there is nothing in your textEdit Revert to? please help

Comment: Dude you saved my life ! Crazy this is not included in Xcode..

Comment: OMG perfect answer. Totally saved me from myself!

Answer (score 5):

If you clicked on "discard changes" before committing any changes, your project will become blank and you will find all files in your trash. There is not an whole xcode project there, but you will find all the files which have dates of when you created them. I solved my issue by getting the file I needed from trash. Then I put it back into my project.

Answer (score 0):

I restored it by using Timeline (it's a built-in app in Mac).

give it a try,

Go to Timeline -> locate and select the project file in finder -> Click restore.

that's it.