# How to retrive discarded changes in Xcode?

Tags: ios

I have configured Github in Xcode. When i tried to commit the changes and push into the repository it was working fine. While committing it shown all the files from the project but i selected only one file and committed that change and push it into the repository. i checked repository also that one file only went to the repository. After that in Xcode clicked Discard All Changes option.That's all, All other files in my project are deleted from my system.

Is there any possibility to retrieve those files. Kindly suggest the solution for this issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... XCode asks you for conformation and there is a good reason for that. But I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478358/xcode-any-way-to-recover-code-after-discard-changes) topic, I think it could help you. The first thing to do would be to check your trash.